# redirecting with example1.com/forum/ to example2.com/forum

Tags: redirect

i have an domain name with cpanel, called example1.com
and when i click the 'forum' button in the default.html, the browser address bar change to example1.com/forum/index.php as expected.

and if i click a thread, the browser address bar change to example1.com/forum/forumdisplay.php?fid=xy as expected.

by the way this is the button code of default.html

```
<html>

<marquee> test home page </marquee>
<FORM METHOD="LINK" ACTION="forum/index.php">
<INPUT TYPE="submit" VALUE="Forum">
</FORM>

</html>
```

but i bought a new domain name called example2.com.
so i redirected example1.com to example2.com.
so, when i go to example2.com it shows the 'forum' button as expected.

but when i click the 'forum' button there, browser address bar only shows example2.com
not example2.com/forum/index.php

and even if i click a thread, it still shows just example2.com
but i want the browser address bar to change to
example2.com/forum/forumdisplay.php?fid=xy

not just example2.com all the time

what should i do.
thank you.
sorry i dont know a name for this question, so i had to write long.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain2\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule !^subdir/ /subdir%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC]
```

This will prefix every request for domain2.com with /subdir if it is not already there.